# Loading Images from Firebase Storage using Glide in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage, android-glide

I use `Glide` to load my images from `Firebase Storage` in `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

The problem is ,  sometimes all images load but when I scroll up or down , images disappear and maybe come again and maybe not . And also maybe load the first image only . How can I avoid this

Here is my `model` .

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity`

```
imageNames.add(0,"first.jpg");
    imageNames.add(1,"second.jpg");
    imageNames.add(2,"third.jpg");
    imageNames.add(3,"fourth.jpg");

    for(int i=0;i<imageNames.size();i++) {
        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("filee/" + imageNames.get(i));
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String imageURL = uri.toString();
                ImageClass imageClass = new ImageClass();
                imageClass.setName(imageURL);
                list.add(imageClass);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
      adapter = new ImageRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my `adapter`

```
ublic class ImageRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageRecyclerAdapter.myViewHolder> {

List<ImageClass> myClassImageList;
Context context;
public ImageRecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<ImageClass> imageClassArrayList) {
    this.myClassImageList = imageClassArrayList;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_layout,parent,false);
    myViewHolder myViewHolder = new myViewHolder(row);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageClass imageClass = myClassImageList.get(position);
    if(myClassImageList.get(position).getName()!=null) {
        Glide.with(context).load(imageClass.getName()).into(holder.imageView);
    }
    else {
        Glide.clear(holder.imageView);
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

    }
}

//....
```

Comment: try adding all your `ImageClass` objects to List as you are doing now inside `for loop` but don't set adapter to recyclerview inside the for loop instead set recyclerview adapter and its linearlayoutmanager out side of for loop when you finish getting the list of your `ImageClass`. `addOnSuccessListener` is `async`. You should set adapter outside firebase methods.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan The problem of scrolling solved thank you . Now still one image load only and just blank spaces for rest of images .

Comment: @MohammedFarhan And I tried to put `inearlayoutmanager` out side of for loop , images didn't appear . I know `addOnSuccessListener` is async but I can't handle this problem .

Comment: @MohammedFarhan I used `Logs` to find out what is exactly happen . I found that , the `URLs` are right in adapter and in my method . But I don't know why sometimes all images appear and sometimes only one appear and the others don't .

Comment: also cross check if your images are with same name and extension in firebase storage under child directory `filee`. And also check if image size is large because if image size is large then sometimes it takes some seconds-minutes to load all images one by one.

Comment: Yes they are the same name and extension . And all images in sometimes appears that means the size of images isn't a problem I think .

Comment: Ok try adding `trim()` method on `getName()`  inside if condition as well as in glide.load `getName().trim()`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan I think it works . But when the last image load , all images appears in last image's scope .

Comment: @MohammedFarhan I found the problem . It was in my layout design :/ . Thank you for your help . But when I scroll up and down ,images reload . How can I stop reloading images while scrolling ?

Comment: Ok try adding  `load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into()`